# Can we use the Macros in Rapid7 to address the issue Attackers might be trying to steal your information from AAA.com for https URL

Tags: macros, rapid7

I have a URL which is having the protocol https. As we are using the self signed certificate for SSL we are getting the screen like below in browser

[image]

If it is in browser we can access the page by clicking on continue unsafe button.

But when we try to have dynamic analysis using Rapid7, we are facing Bad Auth.

We tried using macros also still facing the Bad Auth issue.

Can you please suggest to resolve this issue in Rapid7 Macros authentication?

Comment: Let's Encrypt is free. You can get a certificate without spending money for it.

Comment: We cannot use free SSL certificate for internal reasons